# Resizing GUI components automatically

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have been working with a practice GUI to help me work out concepts before adding them to the real one I am developing at work.

Question:  How do I make the objects on the JPanel dynamically resize when the window is resized?

If anyone has the time and is willing to help me out I will greatly appreciate it.  Here is the "sandbox" GUI I am working with:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PracticeGui extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private List<Point> POINT_LIST = Arrays.asList(new Point[] {
            new Point(40, 40),
            new Point(40, 100),
            new Point(40, 160),
            new Point(40, 220),
            new Point(40, 280),
            new Point(40, 340),
            new Point(40, 400),
            new Point(40, 460),
            new Point(40, 520),
            new Point(40, 580),
            new Point(100, 100),
            new Point(100, 160),
            new Point(100, 220),
            new Point(100, 280),
            new Point(100, 340),
            new Point(100, 400),
            new Point(100, 460),
            new Point(100, 520),
            new Point(100, 580),
            new Point(160, 160),
            new Point(160, 220),
            new Point(160, 280),
            new Point(160, 340),
            new Point(160, 400),
            new Point(160, 460),
            new Point(160, 520),
            new Point(160, 580),
            new Point(220, 220),
            new Point(220, 280),
            new Point(220, 340),
            new Point(220, 400),
            new Point(220, 460),
            new Point(220, 520),
            new Point(220, 580),
            new Point(280, 280),
            new Point(280, 340),
            new Point(280, 400),
            new Point(280, 460),
            new Point(280, 520),
            new Point(280, 580),
            new Point(340, 340),
            new Point(340, 400),
            new Point(340, 460),
            new Point(340, 520),
            new Point(340, 580),
            new Point(400, 400),
            new Point(400, 460),
            new Point(400, 520),
            new Point(400, 580),
            new Point(460, 460),
            new Point(460, 520),
            new Point(460, 580),
            new Point(520, 520),
            new Point(520, 580),
            new Point(580, 580)
    });
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private int tabIndex = 0;

    public PracticeGui() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AddSwitchAction("Add Switch Panel")));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new PushConfigAction("Push Config")));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new ActivateAllAction("Activate All")));  //Button I want to work with

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class AddSwitchAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddSwitchAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tabIndex++;
            String title = "Switch " + tabIndex;
            DrawPanel2 tabComponent = new DrawPanel2(POINT_LIST);
            tabbedPane.add(title, tabComponent);
        }
    }

    private class PushConfigAction extends AbstractAction {
        public PushConfigAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*Add code sending the configuration to the switch panel*/
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PracticeGui.this, "Configuration Pushed to Panel");
        }
    }

    private class ActivateAllAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ActivateAllAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(1);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component comp = tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
            if (comp instanceof DrawPanel2) {
                DrawPanel2 drawPanel = (DrawPanel2) comp;
                drawPanel.activateAll();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PracticeGui mainPanel = new PracticeGui();
        final double version = 0.1;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RF Connection Panel " + version);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 40;
    private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
    private List<Point> points;
    private List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();

    public DrawPanel2(List<Point> points) {
        this.points = points;
        for (Point p : points) {
            int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
            int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            ellipses.add(ellipse);
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

        MyMouseAdapter mListener = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
            g2.fill(ellipse);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    Color c = ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse);
                    c = (c == INACTIVE_COLOR) ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
                    ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, c);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void activateAll() {
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, ACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you could just point an example that highlights the problem you are having, rather than all your code

Comment: I don't see where you have even created any JLabels.

Comment: @FredK I took them out so that people could compile and look at what I was working with if desired, I originally had them in the drawPanel2 class in the drawPanel2 method.  I was trying to add them to the panel the same way the ellipses are added.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Noted for future posts.

Comment: I started to work with your code, but I ran out of energy.  Here's what I was able to do. 1) Add tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(tabComponent); as the last line of the actionPerformed method of the AddSwitchAction class.  2) The preferred size has to be set on the DrawPanel2, not the PracticeGUI.  3) You need to add a component listener to DrawPanel2 so that you're notified when the size changes.  4) You're drawing circles, so you might as well draw the text you want on the left side of each row.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks, I appreciate your efforts!  I will get to work.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't think adding preferred size to DrawPanel2 is the best course of action because when the GUI is initialized you wont see the whole thing.  You will have to click add panel and then resize the window.

Comment: You've outlined 2 requirements but asked no question.  What is your (one, specific) question?  Separate questions should be asked on separate threads.

Comment: @AndrewThompson good point Andrew, my primary question is how to resize the objects within the JPanel dynamically.  If the window is resized how do you make it so that all of the objects resize accordingly?

Comment: *"how do you make it so that all of the objects resize accordingly?"*  If the objects are instances of `Component` - layouts and layout contraints.  If the objects are Java-2D elements, an `AffineTransform` of `Graphics2D.scale(..)`.  -- Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31483180/edit) to ..include the question.  It should not be 'buried' in the comments section.